# Java System Properties reset http.proxyHost and ProxyPort

Tags: java, http, properties, proxy

Simple question, how do I reset the http.proxyHost and http.Proxy properties back to the default?

The reason I ask is I have an application that the end user specifiy's proxy and goes to the next screen.  There may be an event where they go back and decide not to use a proxy.

So I guess the question is how do i set both properties back to the default so no proxy is being used?

Answer (score 3):

You can just clear the proxy.

```
System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
System.clearProperty("http.proxyPort");
```